# Angular passing input values in components without binding

Tags: angular

I have a component in Angular 10 as follows:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.scss']
})
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() totalItems: number = 0;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

and add it to a page like:

```
<app-summary [totalItems]="internalTotalItems"></app-summary>
```

and all works fine as expected when the variable `internalTotalItems` is declared and maintained. I was wondering if it is possible to update the `totalItems` property of the component without having it bound to the variables in the main page?

It becomes a pain if there are lots of inputs all of which need to be declared in the main page, it would be easier to call something like `[app-summary].totalItems=123` or similar.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can reference your component from a parent like this:

```
@ViewChild(AppSummaryComponent)
public comp: AppSummaryComponent | undefined;
```

You can then directly access `public` properties like this:

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  if(this.comp){
    this.comp.totalItems = 123;
  }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this though, using the available input syntax is sufficient.

If you have problems formatting, you should consider using a html formatter, which will nicely format all attributes.

Comment: yea this is kind of what i had in mind. What i was hoping is not to have to declare and manage the variables within the parent component and just update the  <app-summary> value directly if needed